# How OkHttp send text data

Tags: android, sockets, okhttp

I have a java code that send text file data to Label printer
through IP of LAN， It's Works fine

Can this code be executed on android using okhttp instead?

```
try {
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("./src/print.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String string= "";
    while((string=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        stringBuilder.append(string).append("\n");
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    Socket socket=new Socket("10.1.1.1",9100);
    OutputStream outputStream=socket.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(stringBuilder.toString().getBytes());
    socket.close();
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, OkHttp is a HTTP library.  It uses Okio + java's Socket/SSLSocket for most of the low level IO.

The request above is just a simple TCP socket.  You could use Okio operations on top of the socket if you want a nicer API.

Why not just run the code above as is on Android?